# Go MSSQL Connection

Tags: sql-server, go, goland

How do I provide an MSSQL connection? It says it's always connected with the code. Even if the information is incorrect, it does not give errors.

```
package main

import (
    "database/sql"
    "fmt"
    _ "github.com/denisenkom/go-mssqldb"
    "log"
)

var server = "DESKTOP\\SQLEXPRESS"
var port = 1433
var user = "loginx"
var password = "1"
var database = "test"

var db *sql.DB

func main() {
    var err error

    connString := fmt.Sprintf("server=%s;user id=%s;password=%s;port=%d;database=%s;",
        server, user, password, port, database)
    fmt.Println(server, user, password, database)
    conn, err := sql.Open("mssql", connString)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Open connection failed:", err.Error())
    }
    fmt.Printf("Connected!\n")
    defer conn.Close()

}
```

Answer (score 2):

`mssql` in Open() should be `sqlserver`

Try change this.

`db, err = sql.Open("sqlserver", connString)`

So your main() would look like..

```
var db *sql.DB

func main() {
    var err error

    // Create connection string
    connString := fmt.Sprintf("server=%s;user id=%s;password=%s;port=%d",
        server, user, password, port)

    // Create connection pool
    db, err = sql.Open("sqlserver", connString)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Error creating connection pool: " + err.Error())
    }
    log.Printf("Connected!\n")

    // Close the database connection pool after program executes
    defer db.Close()
}
```

Comment: Please make sure you used `db` unplaced of `conn` as updated in solution.

Comment: @Corbas save this https://pastebin.com/tyiKz2U6 and try run `go run connect.go` what is the output?

Comment: Still same: Error pinging database: Unable to get instances from Sql Server Browser on host DESKTOP: read udp

Comment: It mean, you mssql instance is not open to accept connect. Please check with server administrator. At least your connect issue has resolved :)

Comment: I try local connection.I can connect with c# or another one.

Comment: Desktop is your computer name?

Comment: Yes my computer name is Desktop :)

Comment: In Win 10, note that to let ip connect to DB works, you need to enable TCP/IP in SQL Server Configuration Manager (see this link) , in the Service set the SQL Server Browser Stratup type to Automatic (see this link), and configure Database Engine Access in Windows Firewall.

Comment: Check the thread here https://github.com/denisenkom/go-mssqldb/issues/176

Comment: May be "the problem" is that `database/sql.DB.Open()` is not defined to _actually establish a connection,_ and this is only done on the first real use of that connection? I'd suggest reading through [this tutorial](http://go-database-sql.org) — in particular, [this part of it](http://go-database-sql.org/accessing.html).