# Golang Unable to get instances from Sql Server Browser on host

Tags: sql-server, go

I can't provide an Mssql connection. What's the problem?

> Unable to get instances from Sql Server Browser on host DESKTOP-A:
>   read udp [8c32%vEthernet (Default Switch)]:55199->[8c32%vEthernet
>   (Default Switch)]:1434: i/o timeout

```golang
package  main

import (
    "database/sql"
    "flag"
    "fmt"
    _ "github.com/denisenkom/go-mssqldb"
)

func main() {
    var (
        userid   = flag.String("U", "loginx", "login_id")
        password = flag.String("P", "1", "password")
        server   = flag.String("S", "DESKTOP-A\\SQLEXPRESS", "server_name[\\instance_name]")
        database = flag.String("d", "test", "db_name")
    )
    flag.Parse()

    dsn := "server=" + *server + ";user id=" + *userid + ";password=" + *password + ";database=" + *database
    db, err := sql.Open("mssql", dsn)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Cannot connect: ", err.Error())
        return
    }
    err = db.Ping()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Cannot connect: ", err.Error())
        return
    }
    defer db.Close()
}
```

Comment: Check the thread here. https://github.com/denisenkom/go-mssqldb/issues/176

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Go MSSQL Connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56411705/go-mssql-connection)

Answer (score 5):

you can use `sqlserver://user:pass@host:1433/instance?database=dbname` as the DSN.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to point out that the default port the Go driver uses is 1434, which is the UDP port for SQLServer. However, in my experience, the server itself almost never uses that port by default. So by supplying the default TCP port, 1433, got it to work for me.